# Block spam from "tell a friend" forms

Tags: email-spam

You have to have a form on your website for people to send an email to a friend if they found something interesting. You can force people to be logged in (which is not a good option in my case). You can make time delay (this is not really urgent email, so it can wait for 5 minutes). Do you have this problem? How would you solve it?

Edit: I am mostly interested in stopping manual spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a problem with automated scripting of your form, or people genuinely using it too much?

The simple solution to the bot problem is a Captcha, such as [ReCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/). The user-friendliness is questionable, but it would perhaps solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**This service has very good anti-spam measures.**

http://www.tellafriendking.com/features.php?showall=1#spam-free

FYI, I am involved with the company, so I'm not entirely unbiased, but we do get a lot of refugees who come to us to end their spam problems with other services or downloaded scripts.

**Edit:**

If you feel the need to vote down, perhaps you should leave a comment too...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something different from all those captcha scripts. Let me tell you what I do:
- I create a md5 hash:

```
$secretWord='TryToHashMe';
$formID='myForm';
$md5Value=md5($secretWord.$formID);

echo '<input type="hidden" name="form-check" value="'.$md5Value.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="bot-check" value="">';
```

those are 2 very simple ways because: 1) auto bots try to fill all your inputs and 2)the hash is not provided, this mean you have a post request from outside your site. The hashing could be extended with some session or cookie, too.

All the best!

Comment: Note that many modern spam bots use iOpus, which runs a full browser environment including scripting, etc, making this solution fairly useless.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Captcha or if you would like something a bit less intrusive, have a simple math problem(which changes) so you just have something like:

```
For spam protection: Type what Two Plus Two is here _________
```

I did this on my personal website and never had a problem(and I had a *lot* of attempts that failed by spambots)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an all-purpose bot filtering solution. I know this is an old post, but a new botnet was discovered that uses these send to a friend modules to send spam (not a new technique but some interesting new advancements).

According to one [security vendor](https://www.incapsula.com/blog/form-filler-bots-do-star-wars.html) (good tips), “At a minimum, they should include a rate-limiting mechanism that will prevent an IP address from issuing unreasonable numbers of requests over a specific period of time. Other DIY solutions are to have all users fill in CAPTCHAs and to enforce registration as a prerequisite to sending out an email message.”